# Guest User "Record Create Task" Permissions

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, workflow, permissions, visual-workflow

Have researched and been working on this for a week with no avail. Really need any help in the right direction because I am so frustrated.

I have a visual workflow that runs perfectly while in Setup as a System Administrator.

However, when I insert the flow into a forcepage site and expose it to the public - The visual workflow gives me an unhandled fault on the Guest User License page account when a **Record Create for a Task is initiated.**

I believe it has to do with permissions for the guest account, but I have activated everything I could find for task and contact along with all of the read, create, edit permissions - but to no avail.

The error message is:

```
Encountered unhandled fault when running process JSDCL_Front_Desk_Sign_In/301A0000000PLo7 exception by user/organization: 00DA0000000CGkf/{4}

UPSERT --- UPSERT FAILED ---  ERRORS :  (CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY) entity type cannot be inserted: Task ---  for SFDC record with ID : null,

caused by element : FlowRecordCreate.Create_Visitor_Record_Sign_In

caused by: UPSERT --- UPSERT FAILED ---  ERRORS :  (CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY) entity type cannot be inserted: Task ---  for SFDC record with ID : null,
```

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: You could have some other real User own the task/event and instead use the 'Related To' > Contact field to hang it off the portal user's contact record.

Comment: Instead of relating the `OwnerId`, look at setting the `WhoId` with your Contact Id and leveraging that association instead.

Comment: Any ideas on how I would do that? I have the WhoId set as someone else already.

Comment: Maybe you can choose another field, or make an 18-character text to hold your Id? There is an upcoming pilot program that would allow you to out custom lookup fields on Activity objects too... worth raising a case.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far - right now I wrote APEX code that works perfectly when the flow is run in setup as System Administrator. However, it still does not create it on public site. Any ideas on how to have the APEX code run as though it was by another user?

Answer (score 5):

**Site Guest User** cannot own `Task` or `Event` activities, neither can Customer Community User, Customer Community Login User or Partner Community User.

The only way for a non-Salesforce-licensed user to own a Task or Event is if they are a logged in **Partner Community Login User**.

This is a restriction on the permission model itself and not something that can be profile enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If the Site Guest User cannot own a Task or Event, can it create them with a different Owner by default?

If this doesn't work (and obviously this is not an ideal answer since it involves Apex), theoretically it might be possible to write an Apex plugin, using a class Without Sharing, to create the Task. Then use the Apex plugin in your flow. I have not confirmed this, however, and clearly we're getting out of "clicks-not-code" mode with this.